# Search Content Processing Issue

Tags: 2013, search, crawl

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm and on my applications server the content processing component is degraded and my search crawl will not complete.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making sure the file system that contains your index is sound. You also have an end point failure which may be that the CPC is not provisioned correctly. Start with a reboot and evaluate the components. Turn logging up to verbose for Search and you will get a TON of information on that is going on dumped to the ULS logs.

I suspect it's a drive failure though.

Comment: Thanks! In the end the problem was that the drive that the index component was pointing to was offline. Now I'm getting a different error:

Comment: The content processing pipeline failed to process the item. ( The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.LocStringIdLookupTable' threw an exception

02/09/2017 14:48:00.88               NodeRunnerContent1-0d991a01-1ad (0x629C)   0x782C  Search                                        Search Platform Services              aiy4z      Unexpected       AssemblyReflector : Failed to load dependency assembly in load context and in load from context. Assembly: BihConsumerInterop System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.

Comment: Glad you soved it, can I get an answer for my reply?